# Blue checkbox like iBooks editing mode.

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview

I'm making and editing mode in an app similar to iBooks editing mode.

Does anybody know if the bluecheckbox is a part of the system or where can i get it?
[image: iBooks checkbox]
Thanks in advance.